# YAML generated by Ruby appears invalid (!omap vs !!omap)

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am trying to parse some YAML generated by some Ruby code (https://github.com/devrandom/gitian-builder/blob/81bf5d70252363a95cb75eea70f8d1d129948013/bin/gbuild#L322). I am trying to parse it using PyYAML. When PyYAML had trouble parsing the YAML, I tried an online validator (http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) and it failed with the following error:

```
ERROR:

could not determine a constructor for the tag '!omap'
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 5:
    --- !omap
        ^
```

I see on the YAML website (can't post more than two links yet) that !!omap appears to be correct, not !omap. So why does Ruby output !omap when `YAML::Omap` is used?

I can't find anything online to explain this behavior.

If you want to see an example of the YAML I am trying to parse, search for the gitian.sigs repo on GitHub under the bitcoin account and look at any of the .assert files there (again, I can't post more than two links).

Comment: This seems like it may be [a bug in Psych](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/e1d7f705da01349b93420cd7f54576949d694a69/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb#L159) (Ruby's standard YAML library); it should be emitting `!!omap` (since omap is part of the `tag:yaml.org,2002` namespace). Maybe try raising a bug report there?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHeald. I just assumed it was something wrong with what I was doing instead of a bug in Psych, because it seems like something that would have come up before now if it really was a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a legacy thing from Syck. While it should be `!!omap`, I was told I should be able to tell my parser that `!omap` is the same as `!!omap`.

See: https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/241

Comment: Leave your question and answer here, don't delete. Your title and description are clear enough that someone else having the same issues can use it to solve their problem. Please accept your own answer, so it is clear this solved your issue and that the problem is solved.

Comment: Syck IIRC was YAML 1.0 (I remember using that in Python ~10 years ago), things have changed a bit since then. But if you would have an omap type imported at the top level of your Python program, PyYAML could have imported as well.